# Collapse no funciona

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, collapse

Estoy intentando aplicar un collapse para hacer un acordeon con bootstrap pero al dar click no reacciona, He probado acceder a bootstrap y a jquery tanto por enlace como descargado en computadpra pero obtengo el mismo resultado. ¿Estoy aplicando algo mal? No se si importe el hecho de que este usando la versión 5.0.0.beta3 de bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#seccion" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse">collapse</a>
            
            <div class="collapse" id="seccion">
            
                <br>
                <div class="well">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et voluptatem vero aspernatur consequuntur non, sed blanditiis reprehenderit nam modi officiis incidunt odit aliquid culpa quidem eligendi qui doloribus veritatis fuga.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
         </div>
       <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
       <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En lugar de `data-toggle` es `data-bs-toggle`.

Comment: Lo cambie y si funciono, muchisimas gracias.